# Manipulate Data Series to Produce Equal but Opposite Betas

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Suppose I have two different series, $A$ and $B$, and perform a single-variable regression of $A$ and $B$ upon a third series, $C$, to get two betas: $Xa$ and $Xb$. Given these initial betas, I want to transform $C$ so that, if I were to re-do the regressions of $A$ and $B$ onto $C$, $Xa$ would be $-1$ and $Xb$ would be $1$.

I think that the solution to this would involve trying to transform $C$ so that $Xa$ and $Xb$ are equal but opposite in magnitude, and then just dividing by that magnitude so that both are $1$. However, I am not quite sure what operations I could use to get to the point where $abs(Xa) = abs(Xb)$.

I initially thought this could be accomplished with the four basic operations (+, -, x, /), but I am not so sure anymore. Any operation is acceptable, however, as long as it maintains the integrity of the data series. I greatly appreciate any help provided!

Comment: Please do not create new threads for the same question: just edit the original. When you do that, think about explaining what you mean by the "integrity" of a data series.

Comment: The original is closed and doesn't seem to be getting much attention...

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.